# what type of energy electrical current have

Tags: current

I'm interested in what kind of energy has electric current ?. For everything I taught in school should have kinetic energy because electrons are on a certain potential within the electric field when the switch is closed then the electrons move and the electric current is "generated" which then should have the kinetic energy. And so I was thinking all the time until I came across this article http://amasci.com/miscon/energ1.html which actually tells me that everything I know about the electric current is wrong On the other hand, I wonder if so many books from college ,schools, are spoken in the wrong way It's just a little weird that a huge number of scientists and engineers are actually talking nonsense all the time and so I hope that you can help me clarify my dilemma.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That article is talking about the misuse of the word electricity...

Comment: The irony is strong with this one.

Comment: The irony is strong with this one. ?

Comment: The fellow who created that web site actually posts here from time to time

Comment: Better fit for [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), as this has little to do with electrical engineering. In case of migration, please remove the last lines. The question will probably be shot at anyway over there, but with those last lines included :) ....

Comment: There is too much confusion and espousing of nonsense physics here to make a reasonable answer possible.

Answer (score 5):

In electromagnetism energy is stored in form of electrical and magnetical fields.

Energy flow is described by the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) and [Poynting's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem), which is similar to the Continuity Equation of other forms of energy, basically saying that change of energy per time inside a volume equals rate of energy going through the surface and rate of energy being lost/generated inside the surface of the volume (e.g. by work done).

The Wikipedia article contains this demonstrative picture illustrating Poynting's vector (blue arrows). They allways point into direction of EM energy flow.

[image: Energy flow in a simple electrical circuit]

As you can see electrical energy comes out of the battery (where is was created from chemical energy) goes to the right and goes into the resistor (where it is converted to heat). It does NOT go in a circle (like the charge carrier's net movement).

Answering your question from the comment:
Q: Why are currents and voltages still neccessary?
A: Although this picture shows only electrical field (red arrows) and magnetic field (green arrows) currents and voltages play a role: electrical field is caused by nodes of different potential (voltage) and magnetic field is caused by electrical current through a line.

Comment: please read the  question you answered to something else that I did not ask

Comment: @franjojovanovič - the fact that two hi-rep users give answers that don't suit your demands should make you question your post, not the answers.

Comment: ok then what is the purpose of the voltage and the current if the electric energy  is actually an electromagnetic wave

Comment: @franjo jovanovič: Then please clearify your question. "I'm interested in what kind of energy has electric current ?. " is the only sentence containign a question mark, but the rest of the sencen is not clear. What do you mean, e.g. by "Kind of energy"? Also you say "everything I know about the electric current is wrong". How are we supposed to know YOUR wrong knowledge of electrical current if you don't tell more? Also: summarize the content of the docuemnt you are refering to. Don't expect that everybody reads it...

Comment: @franjo jovanovič: where did you get the EM **wave** from? Poynting vector is also defined for static EM fields (i.e. no waves present).

Comment: what type of energy electrical current have kinetic ,potential,magnetic,mechanical ,.the article says that electrons do not carry energy in fact that they are just a passing phenomenon
then the electric energy is an electromagnetic energy  traveling by wire and no one yet explains how it works in that case the voltage and current are unnecessary

Comment: @franjo jovanovič: Why do you think voltage and current are not neccessary?!? With [lumped element idealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model) voltage and current are just [extensive quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) representing the intensive quantities (E- or B-field strengths respectively).

Comment: @franjo jovanovič: BTW electrons (like any other charged particle) in an electric field **do** carry energy; and it is potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "energy" outside of a context. It is a book keeping measure, a bit like accountancy is for money. You can convert between diffferent currencies, but it is still "money", with a number attached and the capability to create change in the world.

Comment: please read the  question you answered to something else that I did not ask

Comment: @franjojovanovič Well, if you want the boring answer it is energy ***stored*** in the electromagnetic field. But that still does not define energy as something you can visualize

Comment: can you then explain what their function is?

Comment: @franjojovanovič Not really. I would say the answer to that is beyond contemporary physics

Answer (score 0):

Electrons and charges are the carrier not the energy itself when we use electricity in circuits motors etc.

Electrons do have kinetic energy, but that energy is actually negligible since a) their mass is almost non-existent, and b) the electrons themselves are actually moving quite slowly.

You should think of electricity more like a chain or belt drive. The chain of electrons transmits force and energy to the load, the chain itself has no energy to speak of.

(Well that last part is not quite true. A moving chain has mass and will itself have kinetic energy, but that energy is actually a form of stored energy and is not normally part of the prime energy transfer mechanism you are making use of.)

See [this cross-post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/346324/139766).